# Can Zergs travel use hyperdrive?

Tags: starcraft

How did the Zergs travel from the planet Char to the Terran dominion if it takes several lightyears to travel through space without hyperspace drive?

Comment: Why do you assume they don't have a hyperspace drive?

Answer (score 4):

In the Starcraft setting faster than light travel is made within the "Warp Space".

Zerg have access to the Warp Space by opening portals that connect to a specific planet/place.
Those portals can be opened by several entities: the Overmind, Kerrigan, Behemoths and Leviathans.

[Warp Space in Starcraft Wiki](https://starcraft.fandom.com/wiki/Warp_space)

Comment: Which, if I remember correctly, is also seen in a cutscene in SC1 when the Zerg first invade Aiur.